# Can I reduce CPU usage on a large recursive find + chmod command?

Tags: find, chmod, recursive

I'm using the following command to perform permissions fixes:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 470 {} \;
```

There are many thousands of files to update the permissions on. It also spikes the CPU usage during the run.

A subsequent call that further modifies file permissions using a pure chmod recursive update doesn't spike the CPU

```
sudo chmod 770 -R /path/to/directory
```

What I am looking for:

- A way to reduce CPU usage during this call
- Potentially filtering to files that need the updated permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nice` to set a lower scheduling priority when running the command, or use `renice` to change the priority of an already running process.

```
sudo nice -n 19 find . -type f -exec chmod 470 {} \;
```

You can change find to not return files already matching the mode you're setting as well:

```
sudo nice -n 19 find \! -perm 0470 -and -type f -exec chmod 470 {} \;
```

Comment: well... didn't know about the -perm setting (I really should read the man page more on these common commands). I'm going to play a bit. For the purposes of this answer I'm going to avoid the nice command (although good to know about) because I do need it to be done in a timely fashion. But avoiding redoing perms will be "nice".

Answer (score 1):

The spike in CPU is due to disk activity so the only way to reduce CPU is faster disk.

Comment: Already using SSDs. not sure how much faster i can get.